# Reusing CLOB in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, clob

If I'm gonna reuse my CLOB variable, will reinitializing it to a new value suffice or do I need to use freetemporary function? Do you have any other way (best way) to do this?

```
DECLARE
   message CLOB;
BEGIN

   message := 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.';

   dbms_output.put_line(message);

   message := 'Test';

   dbms_output.put_line(message);

END;
```

OR

```
DECLARE
    message CLOB;
 BEGIN

    message := 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.';

    dbms_output.put_line(message);

    dbms_lob.freetemporary(message);

    message := 'Test';

    dbms_output.put_line(message);

 END;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine (top and bottom version).

See the [Oracle Documentation: PL/SQL Semantics for LOBs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14249/adlob_plsql_semantics.htm#i1006221):

> **CLOB Variables in PL/SQL**
>
> ```
> 1  declare
> 2    myStory CLOB;
> 3    revisedStory CLOB;
> 4    myGist VARCHAR2(100);
> 5    revisedGist VARCHAR2(100);
> 6  BEGIN
> 7  -- select a CLOB column into a CLOB variable
> 8  SELECT Story INTO myStory FROM print_media WHERE product_id=10;
> 9  -- perform VARCHAR2 operations on a CLOB variable
> 10 revisedStory := UPPER(SUBSTR(myStory, 100, 1)); 
> 11 -- revisedStory is a temporary LOB
> 12 -- Concat a VARCHAR2 at the end of a CLOB
> 13 revisedStory := revisedStory || myGist;
> 14 -- The following statement will raise an error because myStory is 
> 15 -- longer than 100 bytes
> 16 myGist := myStory;
> 17 END;
> ```
>
> Please note that in line 10 of "CLOB Variables in PL/SQL", a temporary
>   `CLOB` is implicitly created and is pointed to by the `revisedStory` `CLOB`
>   locator. In the current interface the line can be expanded as:
>
> ```
> buffer VARCHAR2(32000)
> DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(revisedStory);
> buffer := UPPER(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(myStory,100,1));
> DBMS_LOB.WRITE(revisedStory,length(buffer),1, buffer);
> ```
>
> In line 13, `myGist` is appended to the end of the temporary `LOB`, which
>   has the same effect of:
>
> ```
> DBMS_LOB.WRITEAPPEND(revisedStory, myGist, length(myGist));
> ```

So you don't need to call the `DBMS_LOB` procedures as PL/SQL will implicitly convert your code to the appropriate `DBMS_LOB` calls.

You also do not need to free the values as:

> Temporary LOBs created in a program block as a result of a `SELECT` or
>   an assignment are freed automatically at the end of the PL/SQL
>   block/function/procedure. You can choose to free the temporary LOBs to
>   reclaim system resources and temporary tablespace by calling
>   `DBMS_LOB.FREETEMPORARY` on the `CLOB` variable.

But you can choose to manually call this if you want to control when the memory is freed (as you do in the bottom version).

Comment: Thank you! How bout global CLOBs though? Is DBMS_LOB.FREETEMPORARY and assigning a CLOB to NULL the same?

Comment: @superigno That is unclear from the documentation. I would think they are subtly different (i.e. `DBMS_LOB.FREETEMPORARY()` can free all the memory but assigning `NULL` has to retain some memory to know it is a `NULL` value and not some other value but can release the majority of the memory that was previously allocated for text) however, without access to the internal workings that is a guess.